# Is it against the material design ideology to define width and height of images?

Tags: html, css, material-design

I am working on a project with [material design](https://material.io/). And I wanted to set the size of an image, hardcoded as (200x200). I just want to know, am i doing the right thing. Is it against the material design ideology to define width and height of images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not against any frameworks ideology - but it IS against the grain of a squishy responsive adaptive responsible ideology - depending on how you deal with various px density and if you stretch that img larger than 200px - or expect it to adapt after you've set its size explicitly.

Material design is more about layering visually and a set of rules for UI.

Your image should probably be 400px and live in an absolutely sized 200px element.

```
.image-wrapper img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.image-wrapper {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```